# How to convert to Materialized view query with bind variables

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, materialized-views

My environment:

- Oracle Enterprise Edition 12.2 on Azure IaaS
- Linux Red Hat version 7
- Memory: 32GB
- CPU : 8 vCPUs
- Memory Target is set to 16GB.

Let me explain the issue. I am having some problems with a big query that runs through a REST Service in Azure Kubernetes. The query uses a lot of tables and it takes a lot of time when the bind variables are not set. Actually, when the bind variables are informed, the query takes only 1,5 seconds. I tried to convince the team that developed the query to force the parameters to be informed, but they say the requirement is as it is , and that it can't be challenged.

I improved the query as much as I could by creating some indexes that were not present, even I ran a sql tuning task to collect even more details. I tried even to create a new sql profile, based on the recommendations of the Tuning Advisor, but it made the query even slower, so at the end I discarded it. When the query without bind values is running alone, it takes 14 seconds to be completed. However, when the same query is part of a massive stress test ( 10 to 15 threats at the same time ) , some of the processes are dying by timeout, so that the query reaches 60 seconds without finishing.

All the time I am seeing the same wait event : PGA Memory Operation ( In that regards, I tried also to set more PGA, I even increased the default values of the hidden parameters `_pga_max_size` and `_smm_max_size`. I also tried to run it with manual workarea settings, I disabled `pga_aggregated_limit` but nothing of it made the query to run faster or slower.

Just again for clarification: The problem happens when the query has not bind variables set to specific values. Only in this scenario is where I have issues.

My last idea is to create a materialized view with refresh fast on commit. There is very little DML activity on the database, so the data concurrence won't be an issue and I believe there won't be so much locking as a consequence. I read that Oracle has improved a lot the fast refresh on commit since the times of 11g. However, I don't know exactly how should I address it. Should I create one single MVIEW with the whole query or should I split it ?

I would like to have your input in this matter. Or even if you see something that could be optimized. Do not hesitate to ask for any clarification. I tried to add the execution plan to the question, but I reached the maximum body character limit.

Many thanks for your support.

The query is as follows:

```
WITH extDealer
AS (SELECT thirdPartynumber
      FROM    ALFAODS.ODSEXTERNALSYSTEMREFERENCE odsExt
           INNER JOIN
              ALFAODS.OdsThirdParty thirdParty
           ON odsExt.THIRDPARTYID = thirdParty.id
     WHERE odsExt.reference = :1),
selection
AS 
(  SELECT schedule.maturityDate,
                  schedule.id AS schedule_id,
                  schedule.alfascheduleidentifier AS scheduleId,
                  asset.assetidentifier AS assetId,
                  agreement.agreementNumber AS loanId,
                  proposalStatus.DETAIL AS proposalStatusCode,
                  schedule.scheduleStatus AS scheduleStatus,
                  schedule.terminationDate,
                  (CASE
                      WHEN supplier.thirdPartyNumber =
                              thirdPartyDealer.thirdPartyNumber
                      THEN
                         TO_CHAR (supplier.thirdPartyNumber)
                      ELSE
                         '0'
                   END)
                     AS "supplierGPNr",
                  (CASE
                      WHEN proposalStatus.DETAIL = 'RESERVED'
                      THEN
                         '0'
                      WHEN proposalStatus.DETAIL = 'APPROVED'
                      THEN
                         '1'
                      WHEN proposalStatus.DETAIL = 'FINANCED'
                      THEN
                         '2'
                      WHEN proposalStatus.DETAIL = 'CANCELLED'
                      THEN
                         '3'
                      WHEN proposalStatus.DETAIL = 'PRECANCELLED'
                      THEN
                         '3'
                      WHEN proposalStatus.DETAIL = 'CREDITNOTECANCELLED'
                      THEN
                         '3'
                      WHEN proposalStatus.DETAIL = 'WAITING'
                      THEN
                         '4'
                      ELSE
                         '5'
                   END)
                     AS loanState,
                  productId1.DETAIL AS productId1,
                  productId2.DETAIL AS productId2,
                  productId3.DETAIL AS productId3,
                  productId4.DETAIL AS productId4,
                  productId.DETAIL AS wmProductId,
                  asset.serialNumber AS vin,
                  asset.modelName AS modelName,
                  schedule.totalAssetCostFinanced AS loanAmount,
                  (CASE
                      WHEN schedule.capitalOutstanding IS NULL
                      THEN
                         0
                      WHEN schedule.scheduleStatus = 'Proposal'
                      THEN
                         (CASE
                             WHEN proposalStatus.DETAIL = 'WAITING' THEN 0
                             ELSE schedule.capitalOutstanding * (-1)
                          END)
                      ELSE
                         schedule.capitalOutstanding * (-1)
                   END)
                     AS balance,
                  thirdPartyDealer.thirdPartyNumber AS dealerGPNr,
                  thirdPartyDealer.name AS dealerNameShort,
                  TO_DATE (
                     CAST (
                        CASE
                           WHEN (creationDate.DATEFIELD = 0) THEN NULL
                           ELSE creationDate.DATEFIELD
                        END AS NVARCHAR2 (8)),
                     'yyyymmdd')
                     AS creationDate,
                  schedule.activationDate AS activationDate,
                  365 AS "KBSTATE",
                  assetValuationInp.narrative AS invoiceId,
                  (CASE
                      WHEN assetValuationInp.valuation IS NULL THEN 0
                      ELSE assetValuationInp.valuation
                   END)
                     AS invoiceAmount,
                  assetValuationInp.valueDate AS invoiceDate,
                  assetUsageHistory.readingValue AS kilometers,
                  installSchema.DETAIL AS installmentSchemaId,
                  installSchemaVer.DETAIL AS installmentSchemaVersion,
                  interestSchema.DETAIL AS interestSchemaId,
                  interestSchemaVer.DETAIL AS interestSchemaVersion,
                  SUBSTR (asset.serialNumber, -6) AS vinLast6,
                  stockId.DETAIL AS stockId,
                  deliveryLink.DETAIL AS deliveryLink,
                  TO_DATE (
                     CAST (
                        CASE
                           WHEN (deliveryDate.DATEFIELD = 0) THEN NULL
                           ELSE deliveryDate.DATEFIELD
                        END AS NVARCHAR2 (8)),
                     'yyyymmdd')
                     AS deliveryDate,
                  CASE
                     WHEN UPPER (CONCAT (submitter.thirdPartyNumber, '')) IN
                             ('<NONE>', '', 'NULL')
                     THEN
                        0
                     ELSE
                        TO_NUMBER (submitter.thirdPartyNumber)
                  END
                     AS submitterId,
                  agreementAlert.dunningBlock AS dunningBlock,
                  odsInvoicingCompany.code AS "brandId",
                  odsInvoicingCompany.name AS "brand",
                  agrCompany.id AS "mandantId",
                  modelHSN.DETAIL AS hsn,
                  modelTSN.DETAIL AS tsn,
                  briefNumber.DETAIL AS documentNr,
                  schedule.MATURITYDATE AS finalDate
             FROM ALFAODS.OdsScheduleMain schedule
                  INNER JOIN ALFAODS.OdsAgreement agreement
                     ON schedule.agreementId = agreement.id
                        AND agreement.productCode = 'WHS'
                  INNER JOIN ALFAODS.OdsAsset asset
                     ON asset.scheduleId = schedule.id
                  INNER JOIN ALFAODS.OdsThirdParty thirdPartyDealer
                     ON schedule.invCusId = thirdPartyDealer.id
                  INNER JOIN ALFAODS.OdsThirdParty submitter
                     ON schedule.dealerid = submitter.id
                  JOIN ALFAODS.OdsTmpSystemDate dates
                     ON 1 = 1
                  LEFT JOIN ALFAODS.OdsThirdParty supplier
                     ON supplier.id = asset.supplierId
                  LEFT JOIN ALFAODS.ODSTMPCURRENTMISCINFOS installSchema
                     ON installSchema.alfaScheduleIdentifier =
                           schedule.alfaScheduleIdentifier
                        AND installSchema.informationType = 'WINSS'
                  LEFT JOIN ALFAODS.ODSTMPCURRENTMISCINFOS interestSchema
                     ON interestSchema.alfaScheduleIdentifier =
                           schedule.alfaScheduleIdentifier
                        AND interestSchema.informationType = 'WINTS'
                  LEFT JOIN ALFAODS.ODSTMPCURRENTMISCINFOS application
                     ON application.alfaScheduleIdentifier =
                           schedule.alfaScheduleIdentifier
                        AND application.informationType = 'WAPID'
                  LEFT JOIN ALFAODS.ODSTMPCURRENTMISCINFOS productId1
                     ON productId1.alfaScheduleIdentifier =
                           schedule.alfaScheduleIdentifier
                        AND productId1.informationType = 'WPID1'
                        AND (:2 IS NULL
                             OR productId1.DETAIL = NVL (:3, productId1.DETAIL))
                  LEFT JOIN ALFAODS.ODSTMPCURRENTMISCINFOS productId2
                     ON productId2.alfaScheduleIdentifier =
                           schedule.alfaScheduleIdentifier
                        AND productId2.informationType = 'WPID2'
                        AND (:4 IS NULL
                             OR productId2.DETAIL = NVL (:5, productId2.DETAIL))
                  LEFT JOIN ALFAODS.ODSTMPCURRENTMISCINFOS productId3
                     ON productId3.alfaScheduleIdentifier =
                           schedule.alfaScheduleIdentifier
                        AND productId3.informationType = 'WPID3'
                        AND (:6 IS NULL
                             OR productId3.DETAIL = NVL (:7, productId3.DETAIL))
                  LEFT JOIN ALFAODS.ODSTMPCURRENTMISCINFOS productId4
                     ON productId4.alfaScheduleIdentifier =
                           schedule.alfaScheduleIdentifier
                        AND productId4.informationType = 'WPID4'
                        AND (:8 IS NULL
                             OR productId4.DETAIL = NVL (:9, productId4.DETAIL))
                  LEFT JOIN ALFAODS.ODSTMPCURRENTMISCINFOS stockID
                     ON stockID.alfaScheduleIdentifier =
                           schedule.alfaScheduleIdentifier
                        AND stockID.informationType = 'WSTID'
                  LEFT JOIN ALFAODS.ODSTMPCURRENTMISCINFOS proposalStatus
                     ON proposalStatus.alfaScheduleIdentifier =
                           schedule.alfaScheduleIdentifier
                        AND proposalStatus.informationType = 'WPRST'
                  LEFT JOIN ALFAODS.ODSTMPCURRENTMISCINFOS creationDate
                     ON creationDate.alfaScheduleIdentifier =
                           schedule.alfaScheduleIdentifier
                        AND creationDate.informationType = 'WCRDT'
                  LEFT JOIN ALFAODS.ODSTMPCURRENTMISCINFOS installSchemaVer
                     ON installSchemaVer.alfaScheduleIdentifier =
                           schedule.alfaScheduleIdentifier
                        AND installSchemaVer.informationType = 'WINSV'
                  LEFT JOIN ALFAODS.ODSTMPCURRENTMISCINFOS interestSchemaVer
                     ON interestSchemaVer.alfaScheduleIdentifier =
                           schedule.alfaScheduleIdentifier
                        AND interestSchemaVer.informationType = 'WINTV'
                  --           LEFT JOIN ALFAODS.ODSTMPCURRENTMISCINFOS cancellationDate      ON cancellationDate.alfaScheduleIdentifier = schedule.alfaScheduleIdentifier AND cancellationDate.informationType = 'WCD'
                  LEFT JOIN ALFAODS.ODSTMPCURRENTMISCINFOS deliveryLink
                     ON deliveryLink.alfaScheduleIdentifier =
                           schedule.alfaScheduleIdentifier
                        AND deliveryLink.informationType = 'WDLNK'
                  LEFT JOIN ALFAODS.ODSTMPCURRENTMISCINFOS productId
                     ON productId.alfaScheduleIdentifier =
                           schedule.alfaScheduleIdentifier
                        AND productId.informationType = 'WPRID'
                  LEFT JOIN ALFAODS.ODSTMPCURRENTMISCINFOS deliveryDate
                     ON deliveryDate.alfaScheduleIdentifier =
                           schedule.alfaScheduleIdentifier
                        AND deliveryDate.informationType = 'WDELD'
                  LEFT JOIN ALFAODS.ODSTMPCURRENTMISCINFOS netting
                     ON netting.alfaScheduleIdentifier =
                           schedule.alfaScheduleIdentifier
                        AND netting.informationType = 'WNETT'
                  LEFT JOIN ALFAODS.OdsAssetValuation assetValuationInp
                     ON (    assetValuationInp.assetId = asset.id
                         AND assetValuationInp.valueTypeCode = 'INP'
                         AND assetValuationInp.isCurrentForTypeAndSource = 1)
                  LEFT JOIN ALFAODS.OdsAssetUsageHistory assetUsageHistory
                     ON asset.assetidentifier = assetUsageHistory.assetId
                  LEFT JOIN ALFAODS.OdsAgreementAlert agreementAlert
                     ON agreementAlert.agreementId = agreement.id
                  LEFT JOIN ALFAODS.OdsCompany odsInvoicingCompany
                     ON odsInvoicingCompany.id = schedule.invCompanyId
                  LEFT JOIN ALFAODS.OdsCompany agrCompany
                     ON agrCompany.id = schedule.agrCompanyId
                  LEFT JOIN ALFAODS.ODSTMPCURRENTMISCINFOASSET modelHSN
                     ON     modelHSN.assetIdentifier = asset.assetidentifier
                        AND modelHSN.informationType = u'MANUN'
                        AND modelHSN.DETAIL = NVL (:10, modelHSN.DETAIL)
                  LEFT JOIN ALFAODS.ODSTMPCURRENTMISCINFOASSET modelTSN
                     ON     modelTSN.assetIdentifier = asset.assetidentifier
                        AND modelTSN.informationType = u'MODC'
                        AND modelTSN.DETAIL = NVL (:11, modelTSN.DETAIL)
                  LEFT JOIN ALFAODS.ODSTMPCURRENTMISCINFOASSET briefNumber
                     ON     briefNumber.assetIdentifier = asset.assetidentifier
                        AND briefNumber.informationType = u'BNR'
                        AND briefNumber.DETAIL = NVL (:12, briefNumber.DETAIL)
            WHERE (:13 IS NULL
                   OR SUBSTR (asset.serialNumber, -6) IN
                         (    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (NVL (:14, ''),
                                                    '[^,]+',
                                                    1,
                                                    LEVEL)
                                FROM DUAL
                          CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (NVL (:15, ''),
                                                    '[^,]+',
                                                    1,
                                                    LEVEL)
                                        IS NOT NULL))
                  AND (:16 IS NULL
                       OR asset.serialNumber IN
                             (    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (NVL (:17, ''),
                                                        '[^,]+',
                                                        1,
                                                        LEVEL)
                                    FROM DUAL
                              CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (NVL (:18, ''),
                                                        '[^,]+',
                                                        1,
                                                        LEVEL)
                                            IS NOT NULL))
                  AND (:19 IS NULL
                       OR thirdPartyDealer.thirdPartyNumber IN
                             (    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (NVL (:20, ''),
                                                        '[^,]+',
                                                        1,
                                                        LEVEL)
                                    FROM DUAL
                              CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (NVL (:21, ''),
                                                        '[^,]+',
                                                        1,
                                                        LEVEL)
                                            IS NOT NULL))
                  AND (:22 IS NULL
                       OR supplier.thirdPartyNumber IN
                             (    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (NVL (:23, ''),
                                                        '[^,]+',
                                                        1,
                                                        LEVEL)
                                    FROM DUAL
                              CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (NVL (:24, ''),
                                                        '[^,]+',
                                                        1,
                                                        LEVEL)
                                            IS NOT NULL))
                  AND (:25 IS NULL
                       OR thirdPartyDealer.thirdPartyNumber IN
                             (SELECT thirdpartynumber FROM extDealer))
                  AND (:26 IS NULL
                       OR UPPER (proposalStatus.DETAIL) IN
                             (    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (NVL (:27, ''),
                                                        '[^,]+',
                                                        1,
                                                        LEVEL)
                                    FROM DUAL
                              CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (NVL (:28, ''),
                                                        '[^,]+',
                                                        1,
                                                        LEVEL)
                                            IS NOT NULL))
                  AND (:29 IS NULL
                       OR agreement.agreementNumber IN
                             (    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (NVL (:30, ''),
                                                        '[^,]+',
                                                        1,
                                                        LEVEL)
                                    FROM DUAL
                              CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (NVL (:31, ''),
                                                        '[^,]+',
                                                        1,
                                                        LEVEL)
                                            IS NOT NULL))
                  AND (:32 IS NULL OR asset.modelName LIKE '%' || :33 || '%')
                  AND (   :34 IS NULL
                       OR assetValuationInp.narrative = :35
                       OR stockId.DETAIL = :36)
                  AND (:37 IS NULL
                       OR productId1.DETAIL = NVL (:38, productId1.DETAIL))
                  AND (:39 IS NULL
                       OR productId2.DETAIL = NVL (:40, productId2.DETAIL))
                  AND (:41 IS NULL
                       OR productId3.DETAIL = NVL (:42, productId3.DETAIL))
                  AND (:43 IS NULL
                       OR productId4.DETAIL = NVL (:44, productId4.DETAIL))
                  AND ( (:45 IS NULL)
                       OR assetValuationInp.valueDate >=
                             TO_DATE (:46, 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
                  AND ( (:47 IS NULL)
                       OR assetValuationInp.valueDate <=
                             TO_DATE (:48, 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
                  AND ( (:49 IS NULL)
                       OR schedule.activationDate >=
                             TO_DATE (:50, 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
                  AND ( (:51 IS NULL)
                       OR schedule.activationDate <=
                             TO_DATE (:52, 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
                  AND (:53 IS NULL
                       OR modelHSN.DETAIL = NVL (:54, modelHSN.DETAIL))
                  AND (:55 IS NULL
                       OR modelTSN.DETAIL = NVL (:56, modelTSN.DETAIL))
                  AND (:57 IS NULL
                       OR briefNumber.DETAIL = NVL (:58, briefNumber.DETAIL))
                  AND (:59 IS NULL
                       OR (TO_DATE (:60, 'yyyy-MM-dd') <= schedule.MATURITYDATE))
                  AND (:61 IS NULL
                       OR (schedule.SCHEDULESTATUS = 'Live (Primary)'
                           AND TO_DATE (:62, 'yyyy-MM-dd') >=
                                  schedule.MATURITYDATE
                           OR schedule.SCHEDULESTATUS = 'Terminated'
                              AND ADD_MONTHS (
                                     TRUNC (TO_DATE (:63, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),
                                            'MONTH'),
                                     2) >= schedule.MATURITYDATE))
         ORDER BY CASE
                     WHEN UPPER (:64) = 'LOANID' AND UPPER (:65) = 'ASC'
                     THEN
                        agreement.agreementNumber
                  END ASC,
                  CASE
                     WHEN UPPER (:66) = 'LOANID' AND UPPER (:67) <> 'ASC'
                     THEN
                        agreement.agreementNumber
                  END DESC,
                  CASE
                     WHEN UPPER (:68) <> 'LOANID' AND UPPER (:69) = 'ASC'
                     THEN
                        thirdPartyDealer.thirdPartyNumber
                  END ASC,
                  CASE
                     WHEN UPPER (:70) <> 'LOANID' AND UPPER (:71) <> 'ASC'
                     THEN
                        thirdPartyDealer.thirdPartyNumber
                  END DESC       
 OFFSET :72  ROWS FETCH NEXT :73  ROWS ONLY
),
Selection2 
AS (
SELECT
LOANID,
PROPOSALSTATUSCODE,
SCHEDULESTATUS,
"supplierGPNr",
LOANSTATE,
PRODUCTID1,
PRODUCTID2,
PRODUCTID3,
PRODUCTID4,
WMPRODUCTID,
VIN,
MODELNAME,
LOANAMOUNT,
BALANCE,
DEALERGPNR,
DEALERNAMESHORT,
CREATIONDATE,
ACTIVATIONDATE,
CASE WHEN (scheduleStatus = 'Live (Primary)') THEN finalDate
     ELSE (SELECT max(receivable.dueDate)
                   FROM ALFAODS.OdsReceivable receivable
                        INNER JOIN ALFAODS.OdsChargeType chargeType on receivable.recvChargeTypeId = chargeType.id AND chargeType.code = 2
                   WHERE receivable.scheduleId = schedule_id) END AS CANCELLATIONDATE,
KBSTATE,
DOCUMENTNR,
documentStateLoan.DETAIL                   as documentStateLoan,
loanDocumentLocation.DETAIL                as documentLocation,
TO_DATE(CAST(CASE WHEN (loanDocumentDate.DATEFIELD = 0) THEN null
                  ELSE loanDocumentDate.DATEFIELD  END AS NVARCHAR2(8)),  'yyyymmdd')   as documentStatusDate,
typeId.DETAIL             as schwackeCodes,
assetValuation.valuation  as schwackeValue,
INVOICEID,
INVOICEAMOUNT,
INVOICEDATE,
KILOMETERS,
INSTALLMENTSCHEMAID,
0 AS INSTALLMENTSCHEMAVERSION,
INTERESTSCHEMAID,
0 AS INTERESTSCHEMAVERSION,
VINLAST6,
HSN,
TSN,
STOCKID,
NULL AS DELIVERYLINK,
DELIVERYDATE,
SUBMITTERID,
docRepositary.DETAIL as docRepositaryId,
DUNNINGBLOCK,
"brandId",
"brand",
"mandantId",
NULL AS vatDeduction,
NULL AS schwackeDeduction,
NULL AS ignoreRetention,
500 AS TOTAL
FROM selection sel
         LEFT JOIN ALFAODS.ODSTMPCURRENTMISCINFOS documentStateLoan ON documentStateLoan.alfaScheduleIdentifier = sel.scheduleId AND documentStateLoan.informationType = 'WDCLS' AND documentStateLoan.DETAIL= NVL(:74 , documentStateLoan.DETAIL)
         LEFT JOIN ALFAODS.ODSTMPCURRENTMISCINFOS loanDocumentDate  ON loanDocumentDate.alfaScheduleIdentifier = sel.scheduleId AND loanDocumentDate.informationType = 'WCRDT'
         LEFT JOIN ALFAODS.ODSTMPCURRENTMISCINFOS loanDocumentLocation ON loanDocumentLocation.alfaScheduleIdentifier = sel.scheduleId AND loanDocumentLocation.informationType = 'WLDLC' AND loanDocumentLocation.DETAIL = NVL(:75 , loanDocumentLocation.DETAIL)
         LEFT JOIN ALFAODS.ODSTMPCURRENTMISCINFOS docRepositary ON docRepositary.alfaScheduleIdentifier = sel.scheduleId AND docRepositary.informationType = 'WDRID'
         LEFT JOIN ALFAODS.ODSTMPCURRENTMISCINFOASSET typeId ON typeId.assetIdentifier = sel.assetId AND typeId.informationType = u'WTYID'
         LEFT JOIN ALFAODS.OdsAssetValuation assetValuation on (
                   assetValuation.assetId = sel.assetId
                   AND assetValuation.valueTypeCode = 'TTV'
                   AND assetValuation.isCurrentForTypeAndSource = 1)
WHERE
        (:76  IS NULL OR documentStateLoan.DETAIL = NVL(:77 ,documentStateLoan.DETAIL))
      AND
        (:78  IS NULL OR loanDocumentLocation.DETAIL = NVL(:79 ,loanDocumentLocation.DETAIL))
)
SELECT selection2.CANCELLATIONDATE as FINALDATE, selection2.* FROM selection2
where
scheduleStatus = 'Live (Primary)'
or (scheduleStatus  = 'Terminated' and cancellationdate BETWEEN TO_DATE(NVL(:80 , '1900-01-01'), 'yyyy-MM-dd') AND TO_DATE(NVL(:81 ,'9999-12-31'), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, first of all, to answer your question -- there is no way to materialize this ahead of time with bind variables.  You would need to materialize the query with none of the bind-variable conditions and sufficient data presented in the materialized view to evaluate the bind variables against that.

That is,

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW mat1 AS
SELECT ... all the data, no bind variables ...
```

and at runtime:

```
SELECT ... FROM mat1 WHERE ... bind variable conditions ...
```

Your query has a lot of joins.  A `refresh fast on commit` materialized view may be difficult.  If you have Oracle 12.2 look into the `ENABLE ON QUERY COMPUTATION` feature of materialized views.  Basically, you refresh periodically (maybe every day or every few hours, depending on how (un)stable the data is and how long the query takes to run), but Oracle still guarantees real-time, fresh results by supplementing the (slightly stale) materialized view data with data from the materialized view logs.

That all said, I wouldn't go to a materialized view just yet.  Instead, I'd switch to building and executing the query dynamically, based on the conditions that are not null.  As it is, you are putting a lot of stress on the Oracle optimizer, which basically only has two tools to do a good job here: "NVL-OR expansion" and bind-aware cursors.

Both of these give Oracle a way to have different execution plans based on the values given for bind variables.  They're good features, but I just think your query might be a little much for them for me to trust completely.  That's especially true if there are demonstrated problems.

If you build and execute the query dynamically, which is a pain, admittedly, you'll make the CBO's job much easier by submitting a bunch of smaller, more focused queries that are easier to optimize.

When I say, build the queries dynamically, I mean something like this:

```
IF p_param_3rd_party_list IS NULL THEN
  l_sql := l_sql || ' AND NVL(:23,''XXX'') IS NOT NULL';
  l_sql := l_sql || ' AND NVL(:24,''XXX'') IS NOT NULL';
ELSE 
  -- I'm not bothering to convert all the single quotes to double quotes.  Syntax won't 
  -- work, but you get the idea...
  l_sql := l_sql || ' AND (supplier.thirdPartyNumber IN
                         (    SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR (NVL (:23, ''),
                                                    '[^,]+',
                                                    1,
                                                    LEVEL)
                                FROM DUAL
                          CONNECT BY REGEXP_SUBSTR (NVL (:24, ''),
                                                    '[^,]+',
                                                    1,
                                                    LEVEL)
                                        IS NOT NULL))
END IF;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql USING ... all your bind variables
```

It is critical that you still use bind variables, as shown above, even though you are building the query dynamically, for scalability reasons.

The point of the dummy conditions added when the bind variable is NULL is so the final query has the same list of bind variables in the same order, regardless of which parameters are actually given.  That way, you can execute it with one `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE...USING...` command.  Otherwise, it's a huge pain.

Comment: Thank you @Matthew. Can I make the query bind aware using the hint  `/*+ bind_aware */` or it would be ignored  ?

Comment: I cannot convert the query that way, is triggered by a rest service that uses the query embedded in the request.

Comment: Are you saying you can't change the query at all?  How were you going to make use of the materialized view?  Query rewrite?  Or are you saying the request must be a `SELECT` statement, not a procedure call.  If the latter, you can use a pipelined function to do the dynamic execution and have your service `SELECT` from that.

Comment: Perhaps I did not explain myself in the right way. I can change the query, but it has to be a select statement. The pipeline function might be an option, but it rather complicates the thing instead of making it easier. What do you think about using the bind_aware hint ? do you think it will force the CBO to calculate different versions of the plan based on different set of bind variables informed ?

Comment: Hints will never "force" the CBO to do anything.  You can try it out.  I would not be too optimistic.

Comment: I will give you the bounty, mostly because you were the only one who tried to answer the question.

Comment: If you want to use a materialized view, there is direction in my answer.  You'd need to submit the bind variables in the query that uses the materialized view, meaning all the fields you compare bind variables to must be in the `SELECT` list of the materialized view.  You also probably need to use `ENABLE ON QUERY COMPUTATION` to get realtime results because a `FAST REFRESH ON COMMIT` probably isn't an option.  If you get it down to a `SELECT` against a single mat. view, the optimizer might do better with your binds.  Good luck.  Sorry about horking the bounty.